Angular 18 Uncaught EvalError: call to Function() blocked by CSP
I upgraded my Angular App to version 18 and getting this error now:

How do I find out where this is comming from?

The comment of this function states that it should only be used with JIT compiler:
/**
 * Unsafely call the Function constructor with the given string arguments.
 * @security This is a security-sensitive function; any use of this function
 * must go through security review. In particular, it must be assured that it
 * is only called from the JIT compiler, as use in other code can lead to XSS
 * vulnerabilities.
 */

If I understand correctly this function should only be called with the JIT compiler, which should not be used when I build the application with ng build, right?
Where does this call come from and how to fix this issue?

I think JIT is used during run-time.  So the browser is trying to run that to produce code, which a CSP would generally prevent from happening.  More here: https://angular.dev/tools/cli/aot-compiler  (JIT was the default for v8, while >=9 it would default to AOT... but check your angular.json for AOT settings)

There are no settings either for jit or aot. So I assume it should go with standard aot compiler?

Greater than v8, yes.  Your image there seems to show Angular 8?

I think that just the number of functions called. Im on angular 18

something seems to be using JIT compiler.  SSR and "Angular Universal" maybe?  Seems somewhat dangerous to allow this code to be running client-side.

It really was JIT compiler. I did some configurations on the angular.json file and its working now. Very strange because I used the config from a fresh v18 generated project.
